# Why is Rank() OVER PARTITION BY returning too many results

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, rank

I want the results of my query to be the top 3 newest, distinct Campaign Names for each Campaign Type.

My query at the moment is:

```sql
DECLARE @currentRecord varchar(160);
SET @currentRecord = '316827D2-B522-E811-816A-0050569FE3BD';

SELECT DISTINCT
       rs.CampaignName,
       rs.CampaignType,
       rs.receivedon,
       rs.Rank
FROM 
    (SELECT 
         fs_retentioncontact,
         receivedon,
         regardingobjectidname AS CampaignName,
         fs_campaignresponsetypename AS CampaignType,
         RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY fs_campaignresponsetypename, regardingobjectidname
                      ORDER BY receivedon DESC) AS Rank
     FROM 
         dbo.FilteredCampaignResponse) rs
INNER JOIN 
    dbo.FilteredContact ON rs.fs_retentioncontact = dbo.FilteredContact.contactid
WHERE 
    (dbo.FilteredContact.parentcustomerid IN (@currentRecord))
    AND Rank <= 3
ORDER BY 
    CampaignType, receivedon DESC;
```

There may be multiple results for each campaign name as well as campaign response because they are linked to individual contacts but I only want to see the 3 latest unique campaigns for each campaign type.

My query is not partitioning by each individual campaign response type (there are 6 different ones) as I was expecting.  If I remove the `regardingobjectidname` from the `PARTITION BY` I only get a single row in the results when I should be getting 18 rows. This particular company has over 700 campaign responses across the 6 campaign types.

My query is returning 102 rows so it seems to be removing duplicates on campaign name which is part of what I need but not the whole story.

I have read quite a few posts regarding `rank()` on here e.g.
 [how-to-use-rank-in-sql-server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12739208/how-to-use-rank-in-sql-server)
[[ using-sql-rank-for-overall-rank-and-rank-within-a-group]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18536624/using-sql-rank-for-overall-rank-and-rank-within-a-group)[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18536624/using-sql-rank-for-overall-rank-and-rank-within-a-group)
but I am not able to work out what I am doing wrong from their examples. Could it be the positioning of the `'receivedon'` in the `ORDER BY`? or something else?

Comment: FYI, SQL Server 2008 has been out of support for well over a year now, and you should really be looking into upgrade paths ASAP. Also why use `IN (@currentRecord)`? `@currentRecord` is a scalar value so you might as well use the `=` operator there.

Comment: It's almost always an error to repeat a column/expression in the `ORDER BY` that appears in the `PARTITION BY` - by **definition** you know that all rows within each partition have the *same value* for that column/expression. It thus provides no assistance in assigning an ordering to those rows.

Comment: @Larnu - my query is not about the IN(@currentRecord) as that works perfectly well for the reason that it is there.  It is part of a much more complicated query and does a good job that the equals would not do.

Comment: Thank you @Damien_The_Unbeliever for offering help.  I have adjusted the query (and in the post above) but I am still not getting what I need.  Is Rank() the correct expression to be using to get the top 3 of each group?

Answer (score 0):

I have finally worked out from reading a post on another site how to get the top 3 of each group.  I shall post my answer in case it helps anyone else.
I had to use `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY` instead of `RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY` and I also moved the `INNER JOIN` and `WHERE` clause (to filter for the correct company) from the outer query to the inner query.

```
DECLARE @currentRecord varchar(160)
SET @currentRecord='316827D2-B522-E811-816A-0050569FE3BD'
SELECT distinct rs.CampaignName
                ,rs.CampaignType
                , rs.receivedon
                ,RowNum
FROM(
        SELECT fs_retentioncontact
        , receivedon
        , regardingobjectidname AS CampaignName
        ,fs_campaignresponsetypename as CampaignType
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY fs_campaignresponsetypename ORDER BY fs_campaignresponsetypename, receivedon DESC) AS RowNum
        FROM FilteredCampaignResponse
        INNER JOIN dbo.FilteredContact ON fs_retentioncontact = dbo.FilteredContact.contactid
        WHERE(dbo.FilteredContact.parentcustomerid IN (@currentRecord)))rs


WHERE RowNum <=3
ORDER BY CampaignType,receivedon DESC;
```